# On the complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb N$ be the set of all natural numbers. Set
$$d(m, n) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
 0, &\text{if } m = n, \\
1+ \dfrac{1}{m+n}, &\text{if }m\neq n.
\end{array}\right.$$

Prove that $(\mathbb N, d)$ is the complete metric space.

Thanks all for help!

Comment: Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Show that this sequence converges under this metric. Hint: Choose $\epsilon < \dfrac{1}{2}$. In other words, under this metric, a Cauchy sequence eventually becomes constant.

Answer (score 3):

Since $d(m,n)\gt1$ whenever $m\neq n$, the only Cauchy sequences are those that are eventually constant.   But a sequence that is eventually constant converges. Thus $(\Bbb N,d)$ is complete.

Comment: To the proposer:  Let $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Take $n_0\in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n\ge n_0\,( d(x_n,x_{n_0})<1)$. Then $\forall n\ge n_0(x_n=x_{n_0})$. Because $x_n\ne x_{n_0}\implies d(x_n,x_{n_0})>1$  directly from the def'n of $d.$